# Cannot connect to Remote Server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a WAN, and recently I have been unable to Remote into one server. I was able to previously, but just recently, the network was reset due to a power failure, and I have been unable to connect using Remote Desktop Connection.

- The remote server is connected to the domain through a Remote Ethernet Device, which creates a VPN connection. This *is* still functioning correctly
- I *can* `ping` the server, both with the DNS and IP, with no package loss
- Remote Desktop Connection *is* configured on the Server
- I *cannot* connect using Remote Desktop Connection using the DNS name, or the IP, even though I could before
- I *cannot* connect to the RDP port (3389) using `telnet` command
- I *can* access the server in the File Explorer, by entering the DNS name into the address bar (\\SVR02-APP)
- All of this is done off-site. I am attempting all this on a separate subdomain (I am on 192.168.1.* and the Server is on 192.168.2.*)
- The users *have not* changed, so user access is not restricted. (I have attempted to connect using the Domain Administrator, as well as the Local PC Administrator)

Like I said, the network was reset due to a power failure. There was a user on-site that I provided phone support with to re-establish the network. This was done because the user could not access the Printer, shared through the Server.

- Local Network connectivity was re-established, with intermittent latency issues; the User gained network connectivity (could access the internet, and had network connectivity) even though the Network Connection said:

  - Unidentified Network; Internet Access
  - Domain.Name; No Internet
- When trying to re-connect to the printer (through the network share), "nothing happened" - on further investigation, the Control Panel froze when attempting to load Devices and Printers on the Server, and restarting the Print Spooler Process on the Server did fix the connection, temporarily. The next time the user attempted to connect to the printer, the system froze up again

At this point, my only possible suggestion is that the Server might have (for some reason) switched from a Domain Network to a Private Network? I have experienced this once before, and that was the solution to that communication problem, but I cannot confirm this in this situation. The user that was helping to re-establish the connection last time is no longer there, so I can't check this at this time (using the methods I am aware of).

**Is there any way I can check/resolve this issue?**

**EDIT**

I just attempted to `ping` the PC in the same LAN as the Server, and it returned 100% loss (Request timed out); however, I *can* connect to it using Remote Desktop Connection.

I did attempt to connect to the Server through this RDC, with no luck.

Comment: Does this wan connection of yours have a DHCP address? And are you using dynamic-dns to update your DNS IP if/when it changes?

Comment: @tim_stewart the network is using dhcp, and the servers all have static IP addresses. The pcs all have reserved ips based on their subdomain

Comment: Does this wan connection of yours have a DHCP address? And are you using dynamic-dns to update your DNS IP if/when it changes?